# Unexpected value of floor() function in python

Tags: python

```
import numpy
import math

x = numpy.roots([2,-2,(21 - 21**2)])
print x[0], math.floor(x[0])
```

The output is:

```
15.0 14.0
```

and I expect

```
15.0 15.0
```

I don't expect any reason to have the floor equal to 14.0. Please explain!

Comment: I expect x[0] is really 14.999999 or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a function called `fAlmostEqual` before, based on numpy's [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function:

```
import math

def fAlmostEqual(a, b, rtol=1.0000000000000001e-05, atol=1e-08):
    """Checks if the given floats are almost equal. Uses the algorithm
    from numpy.allclose."""
    return math.fabs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * math.fabs(b))
```

Creating a fuzzy floor function based on this:

```
def fuzzyFloor(v):
    """Returns the floor of the given number, unless it is equal to its
    ceiling (within floating point error)."""
    floor = math.floor(v)
    if fAlmostEqual(floor+1, v):
        return floor+1
    return floor

print fuzzyFloor(14.9999999999999)
print fuzzyFloor(15)
print fuzzyFloor(14.99)
print fuzzyFloor(14.5)
```

This prints:

```
15.0
15.0
14.0
14.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that `x[0]` is ever so slightly less than 15 and so `floor` takes the value down to 14. The root finding algorithm is numerical rather than symbolic and floating point arithmetic is not exact.

Comment: Even if you calculate roots using pen and paper, you would see that they will give perfect squares. No reason, for being any less that 15.

Comment: @Shubham That's not how things work on computers unless you use symbolic algorithms. You are not doing so. Print out `repr(x[0])` to understand more.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didnt knew that root calaculation wasn't precise.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers are only *approximations* of some value, and all computations might introduce *rounding errors*.  Printing a floating point-number might also round the number to fewer digits.  Try

```
print repr(x[0]), repr(math.floor(x[0]))
```

to make sure all digits are shown.  I guess it will show something like `14.9999999999999`.

Comment: I guess you are correct. Basically, I wanted a method if the number has a decimal part or not: Classical technique - is floor(x) == x?

Comment: You can expect that every value returned by a numerical root finder will not satisfy `floor(x)==x`. You are not asking a reasonable question. You can't expect exact arithmetic with floating point.

Comment: @SvenMarnach:  I think your answer is incorrect.  His code does not run as advertised.  See my answer.  Also, the output of `print repr(x[0]), repr(math.floor(x[0]))` is `15.0 15.0`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So no technique to know wheather the root is perfect or not?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I am not sure what are you using. In my case its 14.999999998 14 using repr()

Comment: By perfect I presume you mean whether it is an integer? You need symbolic algorithms for that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach:  But perhaps floating point on his computer/os is different than mine.

Comment: @Shubham:  Then I stand corrected.  Sven and David are correct.  This is something you just have to deal with when using floating point.  Is `14.999999998` not close enough for your purposes?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: This may happen because some processors don't strictly conform to IEEE-754, but take the freedom to sometimes do calculations in higher precision than requested.  This leads to a certain degree of non-determinism in floating-point calculations.

Comment: Actually my last comment is piffle. You can solve for the root just as you do now. Then round to the nearest integer. Then evaluate your equation feeding in that integer. If the integer equation is solved then you know you have integer root.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not give the same thing for me:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import math
>>>
>>> x = numpy.roots([2,-2,(21 - 21**2)])
>>> print x[0], math.floor(x[0])
15.0 15.0
```

However, there is a number 14 lurking here.  It's one of the roots:

```
>>> print x
[ 15. -14.]
```

Comment: Well, that's just how it goes. x[0] is probably just slightly greater than 15 on your machine, with your python and your numpy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Understood.  I'll leave my answer up so that others can see my error and be corrected.